# compare two columns and set up conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames

```
df1 

    name gender
    John 1
    Mina 1
    Cici 0
    Dean 1
    Lily 0

df2

    n    g
    King 1
    Cici 1
    Cici 1
    Dean 0
    Juli 0
```

For the two dataframe, I want to return all the rows where

```
df1['name'] == df2['n'] and df1['gender'] != df2['g']
```

Is there any pandas command could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we do `merge`

```
out=df1.merge(df2,left_on='name',right_on='n').query('gender!=g')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following expression will give you boolean result for each row, then if you need those rows separetely, you can use `df1[idx]`

`idx = (df1['name'] == df2['n']) & (df1['gender'] != df2['g'])`

Answer (score 0):

df1['name'] == df2['n'] and (df1['gender'] == True)